# Linux bash check process running

Tags: linux, bash

I am not Linux bash shell expert and I just wanted to check if my java process is still running..
I have written this simple bash shell script to verify if my java process is still executing...but the output is always 'Java is done...'

```
#!/bin/bash

until [ ` pgrep java ` ]; do
    echo Java still running...
    sleep 1
done
echo Java is done...
```

I would like to ask what is wrong in my until statement.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `while` instead of `until`?

Comment: I need to add this into a Kubernetes init container...so I am thinking of using the until command.

Answer (score 0):

In case of [`until`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_03.html), loop executes until the test command executes successfully. As long as this command fails, the loop continues.
In first iteration, while java is running,  `pgrep java` is true and loop body is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `until`, you should change the condition

```
until [ -z ` pgrep java ` ]; do
```

Comment: Sorry I got confused here but it works...Ohh so the -z test if the pgrep command returns an empty string? So if java is no longer running, it returns an empty string..that makes it true right?

Comment: @MarkEstrada Yes, you are right